# how to remove apostrophe ' in my string in r with str package

Tags: r, string, text

How can I remove apostrophe ' (example : "d'un", "d'une", "l'alphabet", ...) in my R text with the str package?

Purpose : remove apostrophe "'" in my R text with the stringr package

Thank you very much for your reply !

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding something. The [`stR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stR/) package is about *"decomposing seasonal data"*, not about string-modification. Why not something like `gsub("'", "", yourstrings)`? Or should I ignore the question title and you want `stringr::str_replace_all(yourstrings, "'", "")`?

Comment: I think the OP means the `stringr` package for which most functions start `str_*`.

Comment: Don't ask **how** to do something,   ask how to get the **result** you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my answer.

There is a difference between "’" and "'". (it's maybe the difference between French and English)

Thank you all for your replies !

Answer (score 1):

The package stringr actually has a shorthand to replace some string with an empty string (i.e., remove strings):

```r
library(stringr)

x <- c("d'un", "d'une", "l'alphabet")
str_remove_all(x, "'")
#> [1] "dun"       "dune"      "lalphabet"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>